# Extra carriage-return on magit path

Tags: magit, microsoft-windows

I'm having a little trouble with magit and the `default-directory` variable.

When calling `M-x magit-status`, an exception is thrown - `Setting current directory: No such file or directory, /path/to/git/repo/^M/`. I.e. there is an extra carriage return character inserted on the end of the path as though it were another directory level.

For the avoidance of doubt, this is not about carriage returns in a repository file, but rather the path to the repository. Emacs is running on windows, with git for windows.

Error trace below:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Setting current directory" "No such file or directory" "c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/")
  call-process("c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(call-process "c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  process-file("c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(process-file "c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-process-file("c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(magit-process-file "c:/Program Files/Git/git-cmd.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-git-insert("config" "--list" "-z")
  apply(magit-git-insert ("config" "--list" "-z"))
  magit-git-items("config" "--list" "-z")
  magit-config-get-from-cached-list("magit.extension")
  magit-get-all("magit.extension")
  magit-load-config-extensions()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook magit-mode-hook magit-status-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook magit-mode-hook magit-status-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(magit-status-mode-hook)
  magit-status-mode()
  magit-setup-buffer-internal(magit-status-mode nil ((magit-buffer-diff-args ("--no-ext-diff")) (magit-buffer-diff-files nil) (magit-buffer-log-args ("-n256" "--decorate")) (magit-buffer-log-files nil)))
  magit-status-setup-buffer("c:/emacs/home/temp/")
  magit-status(nil ((4 . 4) (("c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/") (("c:/emacs/home/temp/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/") (("c:/emacs/home/temp/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "\015")))
  funcall-interactively(magit-status nil ((4 . 4) (("c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/") (("c:/emacs/home/temp/" . magit-toplevel) . "c:/emacs/home/temp/\015/") (("c:/emacs/home/temp/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "\015")))
  call-interactively(magit-status record nil)
  command-execute(magit-status record)
  helm-M-x(nil #("magit-status" 0 12 (match-part "magit-status")))
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil #("magit-status" 0 12 (match-part "magit-status")))
  call-interactively(helm-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

Comment: Is that *actually* the value of `C-h v default-directory` in that buffer? (You've mentioned the variable, but haven't confirmed that it's relevant).  If the buffer you're calling `magit-status` from already has an invalid `default-directory`, then it's not really a Magit issue.  If it's only the Magit status buffer that has the invalid value, please clarify.

Comment: For extra context could you `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the response!
`default-directory` seems to have the path as I would expect - no extra carriage returns.

`default-directory is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is "c:/emacs/home/temp/"`

Comment: Is there a git repo in current dir?  Otherwise, what's the value of the variable magit-repository-directories?

Comment: Current directory is a git repo (temp is just a git repo I setup for this question). `Magit-repository-directories` has a value of `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that third-party "fix and/or improve cygwin" package messes things up. Try with `emacs -Q ...` as documented [here](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html).